Raspberry Pi driving L298 Motor Controller
Im using a RPI5 driving an L298n motor controller to provide power to the track of a model railway.  The code is running on a Mu IDE and is using the GPIOzero Motor library.  It all works exactly as I would expect, except.....  When the STOP button is clicked on the editor, the train more often than not continues around the track at full speed and does not stop as I would expect.  Ive used several L298s and they all behave the same. I would be grateful for any advice to solve this problem

please be aware that nobody here knows what you are doing ... the information provided is only useful to yourself, or to someone that knows what you did

Sorry, i obviously didn't do a very good job of explaining what I want.  In summary I what I need is a way to set the GPIO ports of a raspberry Pi, to either low or high as required by the hardware design, before the program finally exits.  At the moment, when I click STOP on the Mu IDE, they seem go to a random status which causes the hardware, L298n motor controllers, to occasionally output full voltage

you still have not explained anything ... please edit the question ... do not write a comment ... explain what you have, how it is connected (schematic diagram), and what code you are running
